# Is there a difference between assigning a new ID via e.id=X and e.attr("id", X)?

Tags: jquery

Will there be any side-effects if I code:

```
$myEl.id="whatever"
```

instead of

```
$myEl.attr("id","whatever")?
```

Comment: Read the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.id` is a DOM property. `.attr()` is a jQuery method. You can't use them both on the same type of object.

If `$myEl` is a jQuery object, the first needs to be

```
$myEl[0].id = "whatever";
```

If `$myEl` is a DOM element, the second needs to be

```
$(myEl).attr("id", "whatever");
```

The end results of both styles are identical.